# How to resize a UIView on top of a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a custom header, which I would like to "collapse" when a user scrolls:

```
----------      ----------
-        -      - Header -
- Header -      ----------
-        -      -  Body  -
----------  ->  -        -
-  Body  -      -        -
-        -      -        -
-        -      -        -
-        -      -        -
----------      ----------
```

Simply using the Scroll/Table/CollectionView's `contentOffset` property to calculate the header's height is no good, because the top of the body ends up scrolled below the header as it collapses. I would like the user's scrolling action to collapse the header, and then only when the header is fully collapsed, allow the body to scroll content up. How can I go about this? Juggling a gestureRecognizer on top of the scroll view seems overly complicated, but I cannot think of a simpler solution.

Comment: you could try to implement the scrollview delegates but that would still be complicated, other than that i cannot think of anything. Perhaps you could find a library that has this functionality at Github because this seems like a common feature. This might be helpful to you: https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header/

Comment: do you want it to be interactive? I mean you expect the collapse happen in an animation, or is it supposed to be controller by the gesture?

Comment: Create header as separate view on top of scroll view.Stop the scroll initially.Implement touch methods. Collapse the header.Make scroll view replace the position of header (Animate everything). After header is collapsed open scrolling. My thoughts :)